# Can anyone explain how to calculate the execution time of encryption and decryption of a cipher?

Tags: python

I tried to use time function in polybious square cipher but its not working ,is there any other way to calculate the encryption and decryption time of a cipher? or it has any other formula ?plase help me regarding this ..and i wanted to know the encryption and decryption time of polybious square and vignere cipher with any random string length..

thank you

Comment: Please share your attempt so far. What exactly do you mean by "its not working"?

Answer (score -2):

```py
import time

start = time.time()
encrypt_func()
encrypt_duration = time.time() - start
decrypt_func()
decrypt_duration = time.time() - encrypt_duration

print("Encryption took", encrypt_duration, "milliseconds")
print("Decryption took", decrypt_duration, "milliseconds")
```